# xcolor colors showing only black

Tags: color

I recently did a clean install of my OS and ever since I can't get **xcolor** to work on my .tex documents

this is a minimal .tex file I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{test}
\end{document}
```

and the resulting .log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.6-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2014/dev) (format=pdflatex 2014.10.9)  27 NOV 2014 05:27
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**minimal.tex
(./minimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 76 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)
Package xcolor Info: Model `rgb' substituted by `ignore' on input line 1333.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmyk' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1334.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `gray' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
No file minimal.aux.
\openout1 = `minimal.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
[1

{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./minimal.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 708 strings out of 494683
 7949 string characters out of 6167535
 61367 words of memory out of 5000000
 4118 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 28i,5n,44p,138b,114s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr10.pfb>
Output written on minimal.pdf (1 page, 10607 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

what caught my attention is the line where it says `Package xcolor Info: Model 'rgb' substituted by 'ignore' on input line 1333.`, I tried googling it but I can only find other .log files.

Any thoughts on what might be the cause?

**UPDATE**

turns out the problem was due to an error when I installed pdftex that caused my pdftex.def file to be empty, reinstalling texlive-pdftex did the trick

Comment: What happens if you load `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}`?

Comment: same thing happens if I use `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}`, `\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}` or just `\usepackage{xcolor}`

Comment: Your pdftex.def looks curious. I wonder why it doesn't load infwarerr. What version has this file?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand, what version of what file?

Comment: The pdftex.def here `(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def`

Comment: I can reproduce your problem and the output of the log-file by replacing my pdftex.def with an empty file. So it looks as if your pdftex.def is broken.

Comment: uh, weird, apparently that file was blank, along with about 65 other files on my `texmf-dist/tex/latex/` folder, that might be the problem

Comment: It looks like that you are using Ubuntu/Debiab or OpenSuse. Simply reinstall the `pdftex` package.

Comment: that did it, how do I close my question now?

Comment: @M.Faggioni You can delete it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue that was reported appears to be caused by a faulty installation; reinstalling pdftex fixed the problem.